# Converting Base64 string into blob in React Native

Tags: react-native

i have been looking for a solution to convert Image from base64 string into Blob

i get my images via react-native-image-crop-picker

the image object i get is formatted in this way :

```
{ 
creationDate: "1299975445"
cropRect: null
data: "/9j...AA"
duration: null
exif: null
filename: "IMG_0001.JPG"
height: 2848
localIdentifier: "10...001"
mime: "image/jpeg"
modificationDate: "1441224147"
path: "/Users/...351F66445.jpg"
size: 1896240
sourceURL: "file:///Users/...IMG_0001.JPG"
width: 4288
}
```

which means i have the path and source url and image data as base64 string.

what i need is to upload the images that the user picks as blob file to the server.

so is there any way to do the conversion in react native.

ps: i have tried solutions i found online but non of them seems to work so far but none of them seems to work for me.

```
urlToBlob = (url) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onerror = reject;
    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        resolve(xhr.response);
      }
    };
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob'; // convert type
    xhr.send();
  })



this.urlToBlob(data)
        .then((blob) => {
          console.log(blob);
        });
```

i tried this peace of code and this what i got in my console :

```
{
_data:
blobId: "B69744A5-B8D7-4E6B-8D15-1C95069737EA"
name: "Unknown"
offset: 0
size: 1896240
type: "image/jpeg"
__collector: null
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a lot of search i found a solution if anyone faced this issue.
i used a package 'extract-files' it allowed me to the images as files in order to send them to the server
it worked like this:

```
import { ReactNativeFile } from 'extract-files';
const FormData = require('form-data');

_addImage = async () => {
const { images } = this.state;

if (images.imageData.length > 0) {
  const formData = new FormData();


// converting images to files 
  images.imageData.forEach((element) => {
    const file = new ReactNativeFile({
      uri: element.sourceURL,
      name: element.filename,
      type: element.mime,
    });
    formData.append('files', file);
  });

// sending files to the server
  await addImages(formData).then((response) => {
    console.log('response : ', response);
    if (response.success) {
      this.pictures = response.filesNames;
      this.setState({
        isLoading: true,
        pictures: response.filesNames
      });
      return response.success;
    }
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });
}
  }
```

i hope this is helpful

Comment: Hi Do you have the code for addImages() ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the conversion working on my RN 0.70.x:

```
import {decode, encode} from 'base-64';  //<<==yarn add base-64 if not available
// Convert base64 to blob 
    const base64ToUint8Array = (base64) => {
      try {      
        const binaryString = decode(base64); // Decode base64
        const len = binaryString.length;
        const bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
        for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          bytes[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        return bytes;  //<<==blob
      } catch (err) {
        return null;
      };
    }
```